# Using together.js for cobrowsing an Angular.js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, togetherjs

I am trying to implement co-browsing using Together.js on an Angular.js application. While screensharing works and the users can see what each other does on initial view, when the user navigates to a different "view" the together.js doesn't sense this prompt/ nudge the user to follow.

Has anyone got together.js cobrowsing working with an angular.js application?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Together.js are not working properly with angularjs application. You need to update togetherjs to make it work.