# How to synchronize angular apps with togetherjs

Tags: angularjs, togetherjs

I am trying to use togetherjs to make a live help feature for an angular web app.  I put the together code in and it works on a basic level. You can see each other's cursors and chat etc.  The problem is that none of the angular state data syncs. So when someone navigates to a different route the others don't follow them to the route. Is there a way to fix this? I have seen [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296819/) like this on SO but it hasn't been answered and I don't have enough reputation to do anything but answer it and I am seeking the same answer.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The other question being [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296819/using-together-js-for-cobrowsing-an-angular-js-application) in case anyone is curious.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to know for sure, but Angular always has issues with seeing changes to it's data models outside it's control.  Usually wrapping calls to 3rd party apis inside `$scope.apply()` is necessary to initiate a `$digest` within angular.